# Understanding Fedora 'w' and 'last' "FROM" field

Tags: linux, login

I have trouble understanding "FROM" field of 'w'. AFAIK, when someone logins directly on the machine, "TTY" field is tty* and "FROM" is empty; when someone logins via ssh, "TTY" is pts/* and "FROM" is an IP of users machine. Thats quite transparent.

But what if "TTY" is pts/* and "FROM" is like :5.5 or :3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pts is a [pseudo-terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal); :5.5 or :3 are references to X-Windows displays.  So that simply means a terminal was opened inside X-Windows.